# If and else both executed in nested loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In google apps spreadsheet I am parsing json and filling up cells. After seting value to cell I check if the row has this value and if it does I go to the next cell and set new value, then I check the second value and so on. But something goes wrong and the if and else are both executing..

```
var customfields = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('Form').getRange('J25').getValue();
if (customfields == true) {
  var jj = 2;
  var ii = 1;
  for each(item in data) {
    var size = Object.keys(data[k].customfields).length;
    if (size == 0) {
      k = k + 1;
      continue;
    }
    Logger.log(k)

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {

      var vl = data[k].customfields[j].value;
      var nm = data[k].customfields[j].name;

      var rng = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('Data').getMaxColumns();
      for (var cn = 0; cn <= rng; cn++) {

        var dat = sheet.getRange(1, cn).getValue();
        Logger.log("IF STATEMENT")
        if (dat == nm) {
          sheet.getRange(ii, cn).setValue(nm);

        } else {
          sheet.getRange(ii, br).setValue(nm);

        }
      }

      Logger.log(nm)
      br = br + 1;
    }
    k = k + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't increment `ii`.

Comment: Incrementing 'ii' doestn't help. Anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do - your question does not convey your desired task or the specific issue you're having, so getting useful help is going to be difficult unless you can more clearly articulate what your script is doing. Furthermore, this bit: `for each(...)` should really be fixed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in We also never see what `data` is, or even an example of what it is.

Comment: @malomir79 Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?